# Quota and Limit for Connected Sheets Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-bigquery, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

After reading around, google documentation, some stackoverflow posts and other forums, I am still not sure if I understand what are the quotas and limitations for the Data Connector > Connect to BigQuery feature on google spreadsheets (see image below).

Is it fair to say that this feature is an API v4 feature? If yes, limits [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) for API v4 are here

> This version of the Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per
> 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user.
> Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately. There is no daily
> usage limit.

Does it mean that there is not limit in terms of amount of connections?

Practical (extreme) example: it would be technically possible to have 1,000 different spreadsheets with a BQ data connector for the same user at the same time?

Thanks

[image: Data > Data Connector > BigQuery]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the requests from a certain user doesn't reach 500 per 100 seconds per project, 100 requests per 100 seconds per user, then it wouldn't matter how many connections you have. (Unless stated by the Google)

Best to test this is actually doing the said condition but I guess that would be very rare for someone to actually need that. (As you've stated, it would be very extreme condition).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @luamar. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.